# Replace string in SQL issue

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL server and trying to replace string

```
`{ status:"", dateLabel:'', title: 'Initiate'},`
```

from variable @strProgress.

I used below replace function

```
REPLACE(@strProgress, '{ status:"", dateLabel:'', title: 'Initiate'},','')
```

Can any one help me to solve this issue?

Comment: What is the SQL Server version? And what is the expected output?

Comment: SQL 2012.  I want to replace { status:"", dateLabel:'', title: 'Initiate'},  with blank space if it is found in @strProgress

Comment: Escape the quotes - `SELECT REPLACE(@strProgress, '{ status:"", dateLabel:'''', title: ''Initiate''},', '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting an error because you need to escape the single quotes that are within the string.

If you want to replace all instances of `{ status:"", dateLabel:'', title: 'Initiate'},` inside of a string, then you need to escape all single quotes by using double single quotes.

For example:

```sql
SELECT ''''
```

That query will return `'` because the "extra" quote is telling SQL server you want a single quote inside of that string.

So your code should be something like this instead:

```sql
REPLACE(@strProgress, '{ status:"", dateLabel:'''', title: ''Initiate''},','')
```